# Ubuntu 9.10 not detecting screensize and wont let me set the right resolution

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, resolution, nvidia-ion

I have an Acer Aspire Revo which has a Nvidia Ion graphics processor in it. I have it driving a Samsung SyncMaster 2043NW. When i used this monitor with a Windows PC it ran it 1680x1050. In ubuntu it wont go to any 16:10 resolution. Is there any way to force the resolution? or get the nvidia config to pickup the montior as anything other than CRT-0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very wierd, it turned out that it was the VGA cable, it was missing 4 of the pins, not because they where damaged they just arent there

Comment: Does it works now?

Comment: Bummer. (15 char)

Comment: yeah it works fine now, as soon as i changed the cable it auto changed to 1680x1050

Answer (score 0):

that's strange: I have Ubuntu 9.04 64bit and an NVidia gpu, and it runs fine with the 180.44 version of NVidia drivers (1680x1050 monitor resolution).

What happens if you use the command `nvidia-settings` in a terminal?

Are you sure that the permissions are not messed up (or: what is the output of `ls -la /etc/X11/xorg.conf`?).

Later,

Regards